# Comparator help (Lm2903N)

Tags: comparator

I am using a LM2903N to learn about comparators. I am powering the unit with a 9v battery and connecting to the (+) 5v and the (-) 2.5v. However, when I check the output the resulting voltage is 0v. Why is this happening. My wiring diagram looks similar to this picture I created in LTspice. Can anyone help me come up with ideas to try and get this working? Thanks for reading.

[image]

Comment: The LM2903 has an open-collector output. You need a pullup resistor. Reading the datasheet would have quickly cleared this up, there's even a nice "typical application" schematic.

Comment: I looked over the datasheet for 3 days and didn't see the typical application. Thank you for pointing this out and I will go back over the datasheet to get a better understanding of how to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LM2903 has an open collector output so it can not actively drive a positive voltage. You need to add a pull-up resistor of about 10k between the output pin and your positive supply rail.

Comment: The second problem doesn't exist, since when the + input goes more positive  than the - input, the output (if it's properly pulled up or if the output is a totem-pole) will go high.

Comment: @EMFields you're right. I mistakenly thought the 2903 inverted its output.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try making your drawings easier to read, since that makes it much easier for us to follow the circuit's ins and outs.

In general, inputs come from the left and the top of the drawing, and outputs go out the bottom and the right, kinda like this, after adding the pullup to the comparator's output:

[image]

Just for grins - since you want to learn about comparators - it might be fun to take a look at the two circuits below and figure out why VOUT2 switches and VOUT1 doesn't, even though VIN is the same input to both circuits. :)

[image]

Left click on the graphic to make it go full-screen and, by the way, here's the LTspice circuit list just in case you want to play with the circuit(s):

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE -352 -48 -736 -48
WIRE -272 -48 -352 -48
WIRE 256 -48 -272 -48
WIRE 336 -48 256 -48
WIRE -640 -16 -672 -16
WIRE -544 -16 -640 -16
WIRE -448 -16 -544 -16
WIRE 64 -16 -448 -16
WIRE 160 -16 64 -16
WIRE -544 16 -544 -16
WIRE -272 16 -272 -48
WIRE 64 16 64 -16
WIRE 160 16 160 -16
WIRE 336 16 336 -48
WIRE -352 112 -352 -48
WIRE 256 112 256 -48
WIRE -544 128 -544 96
WIRE -384 128 -544 128
WIRE 64 128 64 96
WIRE 224 128 64 128
WIRE -272 144 -272 96
WIRE -272 144 -320 144
WIRE -240 144 -272 144
WIRE 336 144 336 96
WIRE 336 144 288 144
WIRE 368 144 336 144
WIRE -448 160 -448 -16
WIRE -384 160 -448 160
WIRE 160 160 160 96
WIRE 224 160 160 160
WIRE -736 192 -736 -48
WIRE -640 192 -640 -16
WIRE -544 192 -544 128
WIRE -448 192 -448 160
WIRE 64 192 64 128
WIRE 160 192 160 160
WIRE -736 304 -736 272
WIRE -640 304 -640 272
WIRE -640 304 -736 304
WIRE -544 304 -544 272
WIRE -544 304 -640 304
WIRE -448 304 -448 272
WIRE -448 304 -544 304
WIRE -352 304 -352 176
WIRE -352 304 -448 304
WIRE 64 304 64 272
WIRE 64 304 -352 304
WIRE 160 304 160 256
WIRE 160 304 64 304
WIRE 256 304 256 176
WIRE 256 304 160 304
WIRE -736 368 -736 304
FLAG -736 368 0
FLAG -240 144 VOUT1
FLAG 368 144 VOUT2
FLAG -672 -16 VIN
SYMBOL res -560 176 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL res -560 0 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL Comparators\\LT1017 -352 144 R0
SYMATTR InstName U1
SYMBOL res -464 176 R0
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL voltage -736 176 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 12
SYMBOL voltage -640 176 R0
WINDOW 3 24 96 Invisible 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 5 0 10m 10m 0 20m)
SYMBOL res -288 0 R0
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 1000
SYMBOL res 48 176 R0
SYMATTR InstName R6
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL res 48 0 R0
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL Comparators\\LT1017 256 144 R0
SYMATTR InstName U2
SYMBOL res 320 0 R0
SYMATTR InstName R8
SYMATTR Value 1000
SYMBOL diode 144 192 R0
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMATTR Value 1N4148
SYMBOL res 144 0 R0
SYMATTR InstName R7
SYMATTR Value 10k
TEXT -728 336 Left 2 !.tran 100m startup uic
```

Comment: Thanks for the drawings. They helped a lot. I will look into your question. After testing the pull up resistor, I am left wondering when I invert the inputs I do not get 0v like I was expecting. Why is this?

Comment: @MatthewTubbs: 1. Can you describe what you mean by "invert the inputs" by editing your question, please?  2.You'll never get 0V out with GND equal to zero volts, no matter what,  because of the saturation resistance of the comparator's output transistor.   Unfortunately, that 1000 ohm pullup I showed is more than likely causing the problem, and it should be more like 10k for an LM2903.  Sorry 'bout that...  For a better handle on what's going on with an LM2903, take a a look at the [**data sheet**](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/LM/LM393.pdf),  particularly at Figure 3.

Comment: What I see in the diagram above is that with the first comparator the (+) voltage is always greater than the (-) voltage. The Second comparator has it where for the first 1v (+) is greater but then after it nears it's max the (-) become greater.

Comment: Also, thanks for the 10K resistor idea that got the voltage down to what I was hoping to see. One more question thought please?  After I get my desired voltage out of my Comparator, how do I stabilize it so that I can use it on a load? Say I want to use the 12v Vout to make my horn go off on my car. The horn is about 15 ohms.

Comment: @MatthewTubbs: Since your original question has been dealt with to your satisfaction, it's done with.  If you have a new question relating to a car horn, you should ask it separately.